# Annotation as a textbox at the top of a plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, annotations, set

I would like to ask something about Matlab. I could not find this on this forum. 
I would like to create a new text box right at the top of a legend box in a plot. I am trying to do this with a function called annotation, but I am not doing it right because sometimes the new box is over the legend box. Is there any way to do this in order to keep my plot with a good look?

I am using this code:
annotation('textbox',[0.7 0.192 0.1 0.1],'String',{'OOI =',num2str(OOI)});
I've playing on those numbers, but I could not find the right ones yet to do what I want.

I have another question. For some plots, my axes don't start at the point (0,0). It is starting at (0,-something). I would like to know if there is a way to make it start at (0,0). I tried

set(gca,'XTick', [0:20:300]);
set(gca,'YTick',[0:0.1:1]);

but it is not working. 
Could you guys, please, help me?
Any help I would be really glad.

Comment: can you post a minimal working example with the code you use to generate the legend as well? You can use dummy data just for the demo it's going to be easier to understand what is the problem and how to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question with axes at first: you have to set `XLim` and `YLim`, i.e `set(gca,'XLim',[0 1],'YLim',[0 1])`. You should also set `XLimMode`, `YLimMode` to `manual`.

For the question with `textbox`, you should set `Parent` property of `annotation` to be your axes, and set `Units` property of both to `normalized` (or another, but must be the same). From my own experience if you are running version earlier than R2014b, then positioning `annotation` does not work very good, but from R2014b upwards, once you properly set the `Parent` property, positioning is not problem.

Update: small example for you, however you can use Matlab's documentation and google!!!

```
f = figure('Position', [values_in_pixels]);
a = axes('Parent', f);
t = annotation('textbox', [0 0 1 1], 'EdgeColor', 'r');
```

At this point, `t` is an annotation which is child of a hidden object `AnnotationPane`:

```
>> tp = get(t, 'Parent')
tp = 
    AnnotationPane
```

and `tp` is child of your figure `f`:

```
>> isequal(f, get(tp, 'Parent'))
ans =
     1
```

However, `t` is currently positioned according to `f`, since you can see the red border fits to the figure.

Changing `t`'s parent property to be your axes `a` and you see the red border fits to your axes:

```
set(t, 'Parent', a);
```

Change `t`'s position, and you can see `t` is now positioned according to your axes:

```
set(t, 'Position', [.2 .5 .3 .1])
```

Note: since both axes and annotation have `Units = normalized` by default, after you set `t` to be child of `a`, you dont need to care about it while moving or re-positioning your annotation.

Comment: Do you have any example for my textbox? My version of Matlab is 2015a.

Comment: added a small example, hope it helps